# What is an intuitive explanation of Helmholtz equation in acoustics?. What are the prerequisites to understand Helmholtz equation?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, wave-equation

I understand it as the wave equation for a specific frequency component. I have a big picture of partial differential equations but still don't get the Helmholtz equation. Is Helmholtz equation and theorem are same ?

Comment: What are the prerequisites to understand Helmholtz equation ?

Comment: And no they are not the same. Helmholtz theorem is true for any vector field in any science or engineering application that is *sufficiently smooth* ( being twice continously differentiable and vanishing at infinity ) and it relates to how vector field is split into sources, sinks, rotations and low pass components ( well at least if you're an engineer ). You can see the differences between the equation and the theorem on for example wikipedia or wolfram mathworld.

Answer (score 1):

**The Helmholtz equation** (a.t. Wikipedia:) $$\nabla^2A + k^2A = 0$$
Where $A$ is an amplitude, that is: a scalar. The $\nabla$ ( *nabla* ) is the vector operator that does partial differentiation wrt all available spatial dimensions. In this context $\nabla^2$ must mean outer product followed by inner product or in other words: the Laplacian ($\Delta$) resulting in a scalar value, because if it did not, then the addition to the scalar $+k^2A$ would not make sense

---

**The Helmholtz theorem** (or **decomposition**):
Any vector field $\bf F$ being *sufficiently smooth* (twice partially differentiable) can be written as the sum of the **gradient** of a scalar field $\Phi$ and the **vector gradient** of a vector field $\bf A$ : $${\bf F}=-\nabla \Phi + \nabla \times {\bf A}$$

Mathematicians may use + instead, but it is no biggy as simple sign change of $\Phi$ alters that.

---

So the **theorem (decomposition)** is true mathematically for any field that fulfulls the smoothness requirements but the **equation** (as far as I know) is a  mostly physics related differential equation. Like a law of physics.

Comment: The complicated part is that $A$ belongs to a vector space of functions encoding the boundary conditions and hence the geometry of the problem (the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian are not the same for the free space, a violin, a drum or a saxophone)

Comment: @reuns: Yes, I know you are probably right. I just wanted to focus on the basic distinctions first since it seemed to be a question from someone who was new to all things vector analysis.

Comment: mathreadler and @reuns Thank you for the explanations